# Add Product to cart with 0 price and remove FPT from this product Magento 2.4.5

Tags: magento2, cart, tax

I making a promo on Magento 2.4.5 Like buy any specific 5 products and get 1 free. We have products having FPT on them. I want to add this FPT product to cart with 0 price and 0 FPT when someone buy 5 products.

I have achieved this promo by using this event

```
checkout_cart_product_add_after
```

and using this code

```
$product = $this->productRepository->get($productSku);
$product->setTaxClassId(0);
// If the product is not in the cart, create a new item
$item = $this->quoteItemFactory->create();
$item->setProduct($product);
$item->setQty($freeQtyToAdd); // Set the quantity

// Set the final price of the item to 0
$item->setCustomPrice(0);
$item->setOriginalCustomPrice(0);
 // Remove FPT
$item->setTaxAmount(0);
$item->setName('text name');
// Add the item to the cart
$quote->addItem($item);
$quote->collectTotals(); // Recalculate totals
$quote->save();
```

Product price get 0 and its adding to cart but the issue I am having is the price is 0 but its still showing FPT on this product. I want to remove PFT as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try it like this
etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote">
        <plugin name="check_six_products" type="YourVendor\YourModule\Plugin\Quote" sortOrder="1" disabled="false" />
    </type>
</config>

    <?php
namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Plugin;

class Quote
{
    public function afterAddProduct(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $subject, $result, $product, $info = null)
    {
        $cartItems = $subject->getAllItems();

        // Check if all 5 previously added products have 'in_offer' flag set to 'yes'
        $inOfferProductCount = 0;
        foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
            $itemProduct = $item->getProduct();
            if ($itemProduct->getData('in_offer') === 'yes') {
                $inOfferProductCount++;
            }
        }

        if ($inOfferProductCount >= 5) {
            // If all 5 products have 'in_offer' flag set to 'yes', find the 6th product and remove its FPT
            foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
                $itemProduct = $item->getProduct();
                if ($itemProduct->getData('in_offer') === 'yes' && $item->getSku() === $product->getSku()) {
                    $item->setFptAmount(0);
                    $item->setBaseFptAmount(0);
                    $item->setTaxAmount(0);
                    $item->setBaseTaxAmount(0);
                    $item->save();
                }
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

you can modify the code accordingly

i have not tested this code, but do let me know if it works.

Comment: I already did the 0 price part i have issue with remove FPT. FPT is not removing tried many things

Comment: check updated ans